# Вывод сгенерированного html-кода из Custom.php в UMI

Tags: php, umi

Добавил в файл classed/modules/custom.php новый метод cassa(), который на выходе даёт html код:

```
<ul>
<li>Товар 1. Картинка</li>
<li>Товар 2. Картинка</li>
<li>Товар 4. Картинка</li>
</ul>
```

В шаблонизаторе указал:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('udata://custom/cassa/')/udata" />
```

Захожу по адресу этого макроса http://umi.art/udata/custom/cassa в денвере. И вижу что он фильтрует данные:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<udata xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink" module="custom" method="cassa" generation-time="0.022284">&lt;![CDATA[&lt;ul&gt;

```
                &lt;li&gt;
                &lt;img src='/image/164.jpg' width='150' alt='
```

Вроде обернул результат в CDATA, а всё-равно он его фильтрует, выдаёт ошибку, и не выводит в шаблоне. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('udata://custom/cassa/')/udata" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```